# SVN Or Git Users & Permission management

Tags: svn, git, version-control

Which one is better for user management, adding users to special repo and grant special permissions on them (Read or Write).

SVN or GIT ?

Comment: Come on, all your questions are variations of the same question. Pick one, clarify and edit as required, and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout Git with [Gitosis](http://progit.org/book/ch4-7.html) or [Gitolite](http://progit.org/book/ch4-8.html). If your users are already familiar with Subversion, go with it.