# VisualSVN for Linux

Tags: linux, svn, visualsvn-server

I'm looking for an application like VisualSVN in order to manage repositories and also User Access. For example you can create users and assign them to specific projects.

It doesn't matter which version control it works with. If it works with SVN, GIT or Mercurial then it would be perfect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahem. http://serverfault.com/questions/155938/svn-or-git-users-permission-management

Comment: @Tobu, I think he was asking for a GUI for SVN, GIT, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The question I need to ask you is how you want to run your SVN server. If you are accessing SVN via Apache(mod_dav_svn), then you'll need a GUI which allows you to manage the Apache authentication, which could vary. If you are using svnserve, then you need something that edits the built-in permission of the repo. I recommend the Apache mod_dav_svn method. You can have Apache connect to an Ldap server. Then it is possible to allow Windows users to connect quite painlessly. Managing them is also somewhat painless (If you know about AD that is.)

That being said, I recommend websvn: http://www.websvn.info/

Perhaps the thing that websvn is missing that you want is a way to make new repositories. The command for this is very simple. If you have Apache mod_dav_svn set to use SVNParentPath /path/parent instead of SVNPath /path/singlerepo, then you only need to type:

```
svnadmin create /path/parent/newrepo
```

on your linux server and with the user apache runs as or chown the files after.